# How to reload page from Controller JsonResult Action method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Looking for a way to reload/refresh a view page from JsonResult Action method.
I need to reload it from else condition.
The below one does not work, I mean it doesn't refresh StudentsData view.
*This below upload method is a GoogleDriveupload method that upload and display the uploaded file.*

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Upload(string folderName, string contextType = null)
    {
        var currentAuth = Context.UserContextCache;
        var resultList = new List<ViewDataUploadFilesResult>();
        var CurrentContext = HttpContext;
        filesHelper.UploadAndShowResults(CurrentContext, resultList, folderName);
        JsonFiles files = new JsonFiles(resultList);



        if (!resultList.Any())
        {
            return Json("Error");
        }
        else
        {

            currentAuth.UserProfile.IITransferIntakeRequestMade = false;
            Context.UserContextCache = currentAuth;
            GetService<UserProfileService>().Save(Context.UserContextCache.UserProfile);

            //RELOAD SHOULD BE HERE
            RedirectToAction("StudentsData", "Document");

            return Json(files);

        }

    }
```

Comment: Is this action called via ajax? Do you want the view to redirect to another view then use the json on the redirected view?

Answer (score 0):

> Returning Partial View as JSON in MVC

```
public static class RazorViewToString
{
    public static string RenderRazorViewToString(Controller controller, string viewName, object model)
    {
        controller.ViewData.Model = model;
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName);
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
            viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can call this class from your controller by adding NameSpace in your Controller File as following way by passing "this" as parameter to Controller.

```
string result = RenderRazorViewToString(this, "ViewName", model);
```